# share data in perl ithreads

Tags: multithreading, perl

Can I share data between threads. I have a simple code , I have am not able to share data across threads

```
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
my %threads_running :shared = ();
my %thread_data :shared = ();

$thread_data{1}=['a','b'];             #This line gives me an error
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning reference to a shared variable requires to be shared one. You can try,

```
$thread_data{1} = threads::shared::shared_clone(['a','b']);
```

From [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/threads/shared.html)

> *shared_clone* takes a reference, and returns a shared version of its argument, performing a deep copy on any non-shared elements. Any shared elements in the argument are used as is (i.e., they are not cloned).

Answer (score 1):

```
$thread_data{1} = ['a','b'];
```

is equivalent to

```
my @anon = ('a','b');
$thread_data{1} = \@anon;
```

You are trying to store a reference to an unshared variable into a shared variable. That's useless — how could the other threads access `@anon`? — so Perl gives an error.

You want

```
my @anon :shared = ('a','b');
$thread_data{1} = \@anon;
```

Or if you don't mind making a copy of the array,

```
$thread_data{1} = shared_clone(['a','b']);
```

Comment: I need to push data into a shared thread data how can I do this 
    my @anon :shared = ('a','b');
    push @{$thread_data{1}} , \@anon;

Comment: That should work, and so should `push @{ $thread_data{1} }, shared_clone(['a','b']);`